# Calculate GrandTotal of all 12 months

Tags: sql, sql-server

In rows I have one to twelve months.

I have three columns: `Year`, `Month` and total number of enquiries.

I want to add a row at the bottom to calculate the grand total of enquiries:

```
SELECT 
YEAR(date) AS [Year],
MONTH(date) AS [Month],
COUNT(*) 
from EnquiryMaster 
Group By YEAR(date), MONTH(date)
```

Answer (score 3):

Try "WITH ROLLUP" Facility of sql.

```
SELECT YEAR(date),
MONTH(date),
count(*) as data_nums
FROM EnquiryMaster
GROUP BY YEAR(date),MONTH(date) WITH ROLLUP
```

Hope this will helpful to you

Answer (score 2):

You should probably rather show the totals in the UI layer, but if you really wish to do this from SQL Server, you could try something like

```
SELECT  YEAR(date) AS [Year],
        MONTH(date) AS [Month],
        COUNT(*) 
from    EnquiryMaster
Group By    YEAR(date), 
            MONTH(date)
UNION ALL
SELECT  YEAR(date) AS [Year],
        NULL,
        COUNT(*) 
from    EnquiryMaster
Group By    YEAR(date)
```

Also, maybe have a look at [Summarizing Data Using ROLLUP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189305%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

```
     SELECT YEAR(date) AS [Year],
            MONTH(date) AS [Month],
            COUNT(*) 
     from EnquiryMaster 
     Group By YEAR(date), MONTH(date)
```

In this query you will get 12 records for every month for a specific year because you are doing GROUP BY year and month, If you want only one record for a year then you have to remove MONTH(date) from the query.

Query will be like this:-

```
     SELECT YEAR(date) AS [Year],
            MONTH(date) AS [Month],
            COUNT(*) 
     from EnquiryMaster 
     Group By YEAR
```

Comment: This query will give an error for 2 reasons: 1. Invalid Column Name YEAR 2. Column <ColumnName>is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Sorry I did not see you are running this query in SQL Server , this query will work only in MySQL database